# Mavensmate: Deployment not actually overwriting files

Tags: mavensmate, sublime

I'm using Mavensmate to edit Apex Classes on Subl 3. I'm able to pull all of the current classes from my salesforce, and able to edit them locally via sublime. When I save, the Mavensmate console shows success.

I then deploy to server. I run the validation, everything checks out. I select deploy to server, and it returns success. But nothing has actually changed in salesforce! When I refresh the file from server, it loads the old file.

I don't even know where to begin with how to figure out the error.

Here are the steps I'm taking:

1. Get latest file from server (Refresh File From Server:
   [image]
2. Here is current file:

[image]

3. Change last comment:

[image]

4. Save file:

[image]

5. Deploy to Server:

[image]

6. Select Deployment target:

[image]

7. Validate Deployment

[image]

8. Check what changes will be made:

[image]

9. Finish Validate Deploy:

[image]

10. Review Results:

[image]
[image]

11. Deploy!

[image]

12. Result:

[image]

Now let's check on the results in my salesforce developer console:

1. Open up dev console and locate file
2. Result:

[image]

No change...

And if I reload my file from server

[image]

So what successfully deployed? What is going wrong??

Thank you!

Comment: When you save/compile or refresh from server, are you working against a developer edition or sandbox org? I assume you are doing the deploy to a production org, correct?

Comment: To sandbox. The deployment target points to a dev sandbox. Org sandbox specifically

Comment: For the record, our production doesn't have this script at all. So hitting "refresh from server" is returning the script from the org sandbox. So it's pulling correctly, just not saving

Comment: So you are compiling and deploying against a single sandbox instance? Typically the save/compile step will be updating the apex class in the Salesforce sandbox org. You don't need to then deploy it unless you want to send it to a different org. If the refresh from server  isn't returning the updated apex classes then something has gone wrong with the initial save/compile step.

Comment: Immediately after you have saved the changes to the Apex class and got back a Compiling Result: Success, check if the Apex class has updated in the corresponding org in the developer console.

Comment: When I first tested mavenmate, I thought I remember simply saving and it would update the sandbox. But when this wasn't working, I tried the deploy. I can pull from the sand box, so the connection is there. When I hit save, it shows success in the mavenmate console. How can I fix?

Comment: Check your Project/User/Default settings for `mm_compile_on_save`. Mine is true, which means when I save the file in sublime it is sent to Salesforce to be compiled. Also check what `mm_compile_with_tooling_api` is set to.

Comment: I just had this problem in the past week. Mavensmate was reporting that classes compiled OK but when I inspected the class file on the server after a change, it still had the old file version. It was actually compiling, because it would correctly report any syntax errors. I already had mm_compile_on_save set to true, but what fixed it for me was also changing "mm_start_mavensmate_app" to true.

Comment: has this actually been fixed or something? i am having the exact same results: deploying to QA-sandbox successfully but developer-console shows old state